# Show that the following function is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx
\end{equation}

I know that this function has been tackled from other perspectives, but I haven't been able to find anything on its Lebesgue integrability.

It seems to me that it is possible to factor the function in such a way as to show that the function is the product of another function and the sum of a geometric series, and so, it is Lebesgue integrable, by the monotone convergence theorem, but I am having trouble proving this to be true, and evaluating the resulting integral.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx ~=~ n!~\zeta(n+1),~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx ~=~ n!~\eta(n+1),~$ see the [Riemann $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $x=0$, the function may be extended by continuity, since
$$
\frac{x}{e^x-1} \sim 1
$$ On the other hand we have, as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
\frac{x^3}{e^x-1} \to 0
$$ then there exists an $M>0$ such that 
$$
\left|\frac{x^3}{e^x-1} \right|<1, \quad x>M,
$$ or equivalently
$$
\left|\frac{x}{e^x-1} \right|<\frac1{x^2}, \quad x>M,
$$ giving the convergence near $+\infty$ and your initial integral is **convergent**.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=0$ it has a removable singularity: the limit is $1$. So, it is integrable on $[0,1]$.

On $[1,\infty)$ we have that $\frac{x}{e^x-1}\leq \frac{x}{(1+x/3)^3-1}=\frac{1}{1+x/3+x^2/9}\leq \frac{9}{x^2}.$